# No "new document" option in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

As of Ubuntu 20.04, nautilus doesn't show a "New Document" option in the alt menu. I have created a Templates dir with an empty document, I have tried a .Templates dir, neither did work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the line "XDG_TEPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Templates" in the "~/.config/user-dirs.dirs" file and restart nautilus.